# How to select a option from drop down using select_list comment in capybara page-object

Tags: pageobjects, page-object-gem

For HTML like this:

```
<select class="intl_drop" name="select_locale">
  <option value="0">- Select One -</option>
  <option value="1">United States - English</option>
  <option value="2">United States - Español</option>
  <option value="3">Canada - English</option>
```

when I try to select the option using

```
select_list(:select_lang, :class => "intl_drop", :index => 1)
```

I'm getting the error message

```
Unable to locate element{"method":"xpath","selector":".//select[@class=' intl_drop'][2]"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
```

It works fine when I do not use the index value.

Comment: Please share relevant HTML and the entire error message.

Comment: Hi,HTML format:
<select class="intl_drop" name="select_locale">
<option value="0">- Select One -</option>
<option value="1">United States - English</option>
<option value="2">United States - Español</option>
<option value="3">Canada - English</option>
when I try to select the option using
**select_list(:select_lang, :class => "intl_drop", :index => 1)**
I'm getting the error message as
**Unable to locate element{"method":"xpath","selector":".//select[@class='
intl_drop'][2]"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)**
But I'm getting pass when I give the code without the index value

Comment: For future reference, you can edit the question, like I just did.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question the problem is that this works:

```
select_list(:select_lang, :class => "intl_drop")
```

but this does not work:

```
select_list(:select_lang, :class => "intl_drop", :index => 1)
```

The problem could be that there is only one select list with `class` `intl_drop`.

`:index => 1` will select **the second** element.  `:index => 0` will select the first one.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  The next question is if there is only one of the select lists on the page why provide an index?

Comment: @Cheezy: I did not ask the question, I just edited it. A Kumar has asked the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
select_list(:select_lang, name="select_locale")
```

and based off of what you're statement you want to select the object by index or value?

```
select_lang_element.select_value(1)
```

or

```
select_lang_element[1].click
```

these both work for me. A long winded way that is deprecated is

```
select_lang_element.option[:value, '1'].click
```

hope this helps.